# OAF R12.2.6 error Message - Key Need_by_date not found in the bundle oracle.jbo.CSMessageBundle

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, oracle-ebs

Oracle EBS R12.2.6 - OAF page

am getting below error when I choose a past date.Actually I should see the message defined in Need_by_date key

> error Message - Key Need_by_date not found in the bundle 
>   oracle.jbo.CSMessageBundle

can anyone help me to understand this error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay.. PFB the fix.

There was no jbo folder(files) under $JAVA_TOP/Oracle path. 
As a temporary fix , took the file from 11i and placed.

recompiled the java files , which access the jbo folder.

ran adcgnjar and bounce APACHE + OACORE.

issue resolved